# Access won't insert a new record into my table if it already contains a record

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I posted about this last week, but my wedding was at the end of the week, so I've been away for the past 5 days, so I'm trying again to see if I can get some help.

A lot of people have asked me why I'm not using a bound form, I tried that and couldn't get it to do what I wanted. I am new to Access and VBA in general, so the extent of my knowledge is following YouTube tutorials, but by all means if someone can walk me through how to create the bound form and everything, I'll take your advice.

Essentially I have a table with the data and then I want a form that has a text box for each field in the table with a subtable of the main table incorporated into the form. The user fills in the text boxes with the information and then either adds it to the table or they can click on a record and edit it or delete it with the corresponding buttons on the form.

I was having some issues with some syntax and recently fixed that today, so now I'm finally fine tuning stuff on my form. The only issue I'm having now is that if there is already a record in the table, the form won't insert a new record once I click the add button. I fill the text boxes in and click the 'Add' button and the form refreshes like the add command worked, but then the new record doesn't show up in the table. However if I go back to the table and delete any record that is already in the table and then go back to the form and fill the boxes in again and click the 'Add' button, then a new record is inserted into the form.

I created a database before the one I'm currently working on and it works fine. It is very similar to the database that I'm working on now, so I just copied it and then renamed the fields and text boxes and everything to match the information that this database will be handling.

Any ideas what's going on here and how I could fix?

Here's a link to some screenshots of the database: https://imgur.com/a/QvCY2

Here's my code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'when we click on button Add there are two options
    '1. for insert
    '2. for update
    If Me.txtICN.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'this is for insert new
        'add data to table
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblInventory(ICN, manu, model, serial, descr, dateRec, dateRem, dispo, flgDispo, project, AMCA, UL, comments) " & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.txtICN & ", '" & Me.txtManu & "', '" & Me.txtModel & "', '" & Me.txtSerial & "', '" & Me.txtDescr & "', '" & Me.txtDateRec & "', '" & Me.txtDateRem & "', '" & Me.txtDispo & "', '" & Me.chkFlg & "', '" & Me.txtProject & "', '" & Me.txtAMCA & "', '" & Me.txtUL & "', '" & Me.txtComments & "')"
    Else
        'otherwise (Tag of txtICN stores the ICN of item to be modified)
        CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblInventory " & _
        " SET ICN = " & Me.txtICN & _
        ", manu = '" & Me.txtManu & "'" & _
        ", model = '" & Me.txtModel & "'" & _
        ", serial = '" & Me.txtSerial & "'" & _
        ", descr = '" & Me.txtDescr & "'" & _
        ", dateRec = '" & Me.txtDateRec & "'" & _
        ", dateRem = '" & Me.txtDateRem & "'" & _
        ", dispo = '" & Me.txtDispo & "'" & _
        ", flgDispo = '" & Me.chkFlg & "'" & _
        ", project = '" & Me.txtProject & "'" & _
        ", AMCA = '" & Me.txtAMCA & "'" & _
        ", UL = '" & Me.txtUL & "'" & _
        ", comments = '" & Me.txtComments & "'" & _
        " WHERE ICN = " & Me.txtICN.Tag
    End If

    'clear form
    cmdClear_Click
    'refresh data in list on form
    frmInventorySub.Form.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    Me.txtICN = ""
    Me.txtManu = ""
    Me.txtModel = ""
    Me.txtSerial = ""
    Me.txtDescr = ""
    Me.txtDateRec = ""
    Me.txtDateRem = ""
    Me.txtDispo = ""
    Me.chkFlg = ""
    Me.txtProject = ""
    Me.txtAMCA = ""
    Me.txtUL = ""
    Me.txtComments = ""

    'focus on ID text box
    Me.txtICN.SetFocus
    'set button edit to enable
    Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    'change caption of button add to Add
    Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Add"
    'clear tag on txtICN for reset new
    Me.txtICN.Tag = ""
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    'delete record
    'check existing selected record
    If Not (Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'confirm delete
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this item?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            'delete now
            CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblInventory " & _
                "WHERE ICN =" & Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.Fields("ICN")
            'refresh data in list
            Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Requery
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
    'check whether there exists data in list
    If Not (Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'get data to text box control
        With Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset
            Me.txtICN = .Fields("ICN")
            Me.txtManu = .Fields("manu")
            Me.txtModel = .Fields("model")
            Me.txtSerial = .Fields("serial")
            Me.txtDescr = .Fields("descr")
            Me.txtDateRec = .Fields("dateRec")
            Me.txtDateRem = .Fields("dateRem")
            Me.txtDispo = .Fields("dispo")
            Me.chkFlg = .Fields("flgDispo")
            Me.txtProject = .Fields("project")
            Me.txtAMCA = .Fields("AMCA")
            Me.txtUL = .Fields("UL")
            Me.txtComments = .Fields("comments")
            'store id of item in Tag of txtICN in case ICN is modified
            Me.txtICN.Tag = .Fields("ICN")
            'change caption of button add to Update
            Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Update"
            'disable button edit
            Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have unique index on one or more fields, identical values cannot be inserted. That said, why this bunch of code when you can delete all of it and bind the form to the table?

Comment: I tried binding the form to the table, but I don't fully understand how to then get the form to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That was what was wrong though, I had a few of the fields in my table set to indexed, so I changed those and now it's working fine.

Comment: Mark the table and run the form create wizard, and you are done.